# Using multiple "WHERE IN" with Python 3 and SQLite, while making it readable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I managed with to get a single `WHERE IN` working, however it looks horrible and I can't figure out how to do add a second `WHERE IN`. I currently have this, which is working:

```
selected_years = ['2018', '2019']
cur.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM journal WHERE year IN (%s) ORDER BY date" % ','.join(
        '?' * len(selected_years)
    ),
    selected_years
)
return cur.fetchall()
```

However, I really don't like the look of it, it's unreadable and looks primitive, there has to be a way using the updated Python 3 way for example using f-strings `f"String to format {variable_name}"`

On top of that, I need to add another filter like such:

```
SELECT * FROM journal WHERE year IN ('2018', '2019') AND month IN ('01', '04', '11') ORDER BY date
```

I managed to make it work with 2 filters, but in a dodgy way without sending the vars as a second parameter. Furthermore, it crashes when the list contains only one element as the tuple is formatted like such: `WHERE year in (2018,)` with an extra comma.

```
selected_years = tuple(selected_years)
selected_months = tuple(selected_months)
cur.execute(f"-- SELECT * FROM journal WHERE year IN {selected_years} AND month IN {selected_months} ORDER BY date")
```

Anybody can recommend an updated way that is still readable? I can only find old answers on Stack Overflow from 2008-2012 with Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can try the follows, assuming you are using pymysql

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM journal WHERE year IN %s AND month IN %s ORDER BY date", (selected_years, selected_months))
```

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in my question, I use SQLite, not MySQL

Comment: Well Both SQLite and MySQL can run SQL commands right, so perhaps try out the query in your code and see if it works @NaturalBornCamper